# How to use predicate value inside another predicate

Tags: prolog

My rules looks like this.

```
cars(ferrari, 320).
cars(ford, 270).
cars(mercedes, 280).
cars(toyota, 220).
```

I have a predicate in which I want to check if a specific car is faster.

```
is_faster(Carmodel):-
  cars(Carmodel,X),
  X > 250.
```

So when I write is_faster(ferrari), I expect to get true but when I use `trace`. I find out that the `X` value is not returned?

In my console if I do

```
cars(ferrari,X).
X = 320.
true.
```

So what is wrong with this, why I'm not getting the value inside my predicate.

Comment: `Mercedes` and `Toyota` are variables. Is that really how you have them in your code?.

Comment: Sorry, it was a tipo

Comment: If I use your code and query `is_faster(ferrari)` it succeeds. So I don't see what the problem is. If you run `trace` you might see an "anonymous" variable used instead of the name `X`. An anonymous variable begins with `_`. That's normal.

Comment: Ok, I was expecting trace to shows the value 320 instead of a anonymous" variable. i undestand now.

Comment: When I do a `trace` it shows 320. I'd put it in a comment, but formatting would be messy, so I show it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should really be a comment, but comments don't allow formatted text, which is needed to illustrate `trace`.

When you load your code as you have stated it in SWI Prolog you should see this:

```
2 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 2 ?- is_faster(ferrari).
   Call: (8) is_faster(ferrari) ? creep
   Call: (9) cars(ferrari, _5220) ? creep     % Anonymous variable _5220 (instead of X)
   Exit: (9) cars(ferrari, 320) ? creep       % Found 320 for ferrari
   Call: (9) 320>250 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 320>250 ? creep
   Exit: (8) is_faster(ferrari) ? creep
true.

[trace] 3 ?-
```